# JavaScript - Insert Character at cursor position IE8 and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I hope some can help me with this issue.

One of our web systems has an online form to submit scientific papers for conferences. In there we have a drop down to insert special characters. The special character varies per client and publisher so we have to do it this way.

The problem we are facing is in IE8 and IE9, all other browsers work fine.

In either one of this two browsers, if we use the drop down to insert the special character it adds it to a random position instead of inserting the character in the cursor position.

I've created a jsfiddle but if you run it, it will work. If you save both files locally and try to run on IE8 or IE9 it wont.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/slfede/d7C6g/2/)

This is the html generated (the pages get generated dinamically from classic asp, there's a lot of legacy code here).

```
<TR>
  <TH ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="5" WIDTH="100%">Page 2 of 4 Abstract details:</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD COLSPAN="5">
    <HR>
  </TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TH ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="5">Abstract Title (max 150 char):</TH>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD ALIGN="LEFT" COLSPAN="5"></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
  <TD COLSPAN="5">
    <SELECT NAME="AbstractTitleChar" id="AbstractTitleChar">
      <OPTION VALUE="">--- Insert character ---</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<alpha>">&alpha; Alpha</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<beta>">&beta; Beta</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<cent>">&cent; Cent</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<copyright>">&copy; Copyright</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<dagger>">&dagger; Dagger</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<degree>">&deg; Degree</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<delta>">&delta; Delta</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<delta1>">&Delta; Delta</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<DoubleDagger>">&Dagger; Double Dagger</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<eacute>">&#233; e-acute accent</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<epsilon>">&epsilon; Epsilon</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<gamma>">&gamma; Gamma</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<greater>">&gt; Greater than</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<GreaterThanEqualTo>">&#8805; Greater Than Equal To</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<less>">&lt; Less than</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<micro>">&micro; Micro</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<omega>">&omega; Omega</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<plusminus>">&plusmn; Plus-Minus</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<pound>">&pound; Pound</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<registered>">&reg; Registered</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<SectionSign>">&sect; Section Sign</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<rho>">&rho; Small 'P'</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<sum>">&sum; Sum</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<sunny>">&sunny sunny</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<trade>">&trade; Trademark</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<yen>">&yen; Yen</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <SELECT NAME="TitleFormatting">
      <OPTION VALUE="">--- Insert formatting ---</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<B>">Bold start</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="</B>">Bold end</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<I>">Italic start</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="</I>">Italic end</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<BR>">Line break</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<P>">New paragraph</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<startsub>">Subscript start</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<endsub>">Subscript end</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<startsup>">Superscript start</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<endsup>">Superscript end</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="<U>">Underline start</OPTION>
      <OPTION VALUE="</U>">Underline end</OPTION>
    </SELECT>
    <input type="hidden" name="Max_Title_Char" value="100" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Max_Text_Char" value="200" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Max_Tables" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Max_Images" value="0" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Max_Extra_Text_Char" value="100" />
    <BR>
    <TEXTAREA CLASS="title" id="AbstractTitle" NAME="Abstract_Title" COLS="80"
    ROWS="3">Crap's Title</TEXTAREA>
    <BR>Character count
    <INPUT TYPE="TEXT" READONLY id="CharCountTitle">&nbsp;&nbsp;
     <FONT COLOR="RED"><B>(maximum: 100)</B></FONT>
<INPUT TYPE="BUTTON" CLASS="button" NAME = "countTitle" VALUE="Count"></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

And this is the javascript

```
function insertAtCaret(areaId, text) {
  var txtarea = document.getElementById(areaId);

  var scrollPos = txtarea.scrollTop;
  var strPos = 0;
  var br = ((txtarea.selectionStart || txtarea.selectionStart == '0') ? "ff" : (document.selection ? "ie" : false));

  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    strPos = range.text.length;
  } else if (br == "ff") strPos = txtarea.selectionStart;
  //alert(strPos);
  var front = (txtarea.value).substring(0, strPos);
  var back = (txtarea.value).substring(strPos, txtarea.value.length);
  //alert(txtarea.value.length);
  txtarea.value = front + text + back;
  strPos = strPos + text.length;
  if (br == "ie") {
    txtarea.focus();
    var range = document.selection.createRange();
    range.moveStart('character', -txtarea.value.length);
    range.moveEnd('character', 0);
    range.select();
  } else if (br == "ff") {
    txtarea.selectionStart = strPos;
    txtarea.selectionEnd = strPos;
    txtarea.focus();
  }
  txtarea.scrollTop = scrollPos;
}

$(document).ready(function () {

  $('select#AbstractTitleChar').change(function () {

    var insertVal = $(this).val();
    var targetVal = $('textarea#AbstractTitle').val();
    insertAtCaret('AbstractTitle', insertVal);
  });
});
```

Comment: jsfiddle has normalized css. Download it and add it to the downloaded site, then it might work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when the drop-down gets focus, the textarea selection is lost in IE. You need to save the selection before the textarea loses focus. In IE, the `blur` event is too late: you need to use the proprietary `beforedeactivate`.

Since you've tagged your question with jQuery, I'm going to suggest using [my jQuery plugin](http://code.google.com/p/rangyinputs/) to make the example simple, although I have published pretty much all of the code in the plugin as standalone functions on Stack Overflow before.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/d7C6g/3/

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var textarea = $("#AbstractTitle");
    var sel;

    // IE specific event
    textarea.on("beforedeactivate", function() {
        textareaSelection = textarea.getSelection();
    });

    $('select#AbstractTitleChar').change(function() {
        var insertVal = $(this).val();
        if (textareaSelection) {
            textarea.setSelection(textareaSelection.start, textareaSelection.end);
        }
        textarea.replaceSelectedText(insertVal);
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks great! Thanks a lot, we'll test this and let you know. The developer I assigned this task to it's already using your plugin now. ;)